# dynamic meta tags with react-helmet and gatsby not working

Tags: seo, gatsby, react-helmet

So I am using react-helmet to create an SEO object in gatsby, the updated meta tags can be seen in the developer tools however when using a web crawler there are none of the dynamic meta tags, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/) along with `react-helmet`.

In your `gatsby-config.js`

```
plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`]
```

This is because you need to serve static properties instead of dynamic ones, so you need to add the drop-in support for the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering).