# How to add meta tags with gatsby which first need to be fetched

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm trying to add META tags for Facebook(`og-tags`). I'm using Gatsby and Helmet. But the problem is that those tags first need to be fetched.

It's a vehicle detail page and I need to show vehicle make and model in those tags, but the vehicle needs first to be fecthed. My code is as follows:

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

const Page = (props) => {
    const [detailsMeta, setDetailsMeta] = useState(undefined);


    const resolveVehicleDetailMeta = async () => {
          const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');

          const resolveVehicleImageUrl = (fetchedImage) => {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(fetchedImage);
            return parsed?.uri
          }

          const VEHICLE_QUERY = `
            query VehicleQuery($reference: String!) {
              vehicle (reference: $reference) {
                reference
                make
                model
                image
              }
            }`;

          await fetch(`/graphql`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              query: VEHICLE_QUERY,
              variables: {
                reference: 'some reference'
              }
            })
          })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((result) => {
          const vehicle = result?.data?.vehicle;
          if(vehicle){
            setDetailsMeta({
              reference: vehicle.reference,
              make: vehicle.make,
              model: vehicle.model,
              image: resolveVehicleImageUrl(vehicle.image)
            })

          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('err', err)
        });
    }

    const renderMetaTitle = () => {
      const ogTitle = `Tweedehands ${detailsMeta?.make} ${detailsMeta?.model} ${detailsMeta?.reference}`

      return ogTitle;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                {detailsMeta && <meta property='og:title' content={renderMetaTitle()} />}
                ...
            </Helmet>

            The rest...
        </>
    )



}
```

And in gatsby config is `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` added. The config file is as follows:

```
const plugins = [
   `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
   ....
]
module.exports = {
  developMiddleware: (app) => {
    app.use(
      '/graphql',
      createProxyMiddleware({
        target: 'http://localhost:8000'
      })
    );
  },
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: `https://${settings.DOMAIN}`
  },
  plugins: plugins
};
```

Thus, I first fetch data from the server and store it in `detailsMeta` and then I show it inside `Helmet`. When I test it on localhost I see those tags and it works fine, but when I test it in Facebook debugger they are not shown.

Can I at all add data to the `og-tags` which **first needs to be fetched** and that it be seen by Facebook?

Thanks.

Comment: Open your access logs and enter your URL in the Facebook Sharing Debugger. You should notice Facebook only fetches the HTML document, no other resources. I don't find proof for that claim but from my understanding, data describing a document must be present when the document loads without further resources evaluated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic meta tags with react-helmet and gatsby not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668416/dynamic-meta-tags-with-react-helmet-and-gatsby-not-working)

Comment: @DanielW. No. Check the answer posted here below.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I at all add data to the `og-tags` which first needs to be fetched
> and that it be seen by Facebook?

Yes but only if you are using statically analyzed data (i.e: using [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/), [static queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query), etc). In that case, you just need to add [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/) in order to add drop-in server-side support to `Helmet` component.

In your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`]
```

*Extracted from https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/*

In your case, you are using the `fetch` method that will be fired on the client-side, so the data won't be statically analyzed hence not present when the Facebook crawler reaches the site. This means that the `Helmet` component will be populated later than the crawler requests it.

I'm not sure about your specs but you can try converting your fetched into GraphQL nodes in order to use pages queries or static queries fulfill the Helmet component properly.

Comment: It's already done in my example above, but it dosn't work.

Comment: Sorry I misread your code. `fetch` methods will be fired asynchronously (meaning in another time-lapse) so at the time that Facebook requests the data, it won't be present. The data won't be statically analyzed.

Comment: You mean "statically served". The meta tag and the information must be present statically in the document, because the analyzer just fetches the document but no other resources thus it does not even evaluate JavaScript. If you get your code to be rendered serverside, the data is served statically.

Comment: Instead of copying your answer you should close-vote the question as duplicate

Comment: @DanielW. It's not copied. It does not answer the question. Read it carefully and you will see.

Comment: @Boky [the problem, the question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668416/dynamic-meta-tags-with-react-helmet-and-gatsby-not-working) are the same. You are trying something that doesn't work with client side rendering. Look at the answers, its a copy.

Comment: @DanielW. There is also not answered and this question is a way better, with the code example and all the rest. Instead of looking if it's copied can you help to solve the problem?

Comment: I gave the helpful comment two hours ago, the data needs to be in the document when it gets requested, not through evaluated javascript.

Comment: @DanielW. I know that, but the question is how to do that if I first need to fetch the data. Your comment was not helpful, your comment was just the short version of the problem in my question.